# How do I get the lookup objects field history tracking to show up in the related list of the child object?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I can see in my org that someone has a lookup to opportunity and can get the history tracking of opportunity in the related list of the custom object.
I tried to do it for another custom object and it didn't work.

To replicate this in a scratch org I created two custom objects custom object 1 and custom object 2.

Custom object 2 has a lookup to custom object 1 and I made a field "status" on 1 and turned on the field history tracking on it. While creating the objects object 1 didn't have field history tracking turned on and I turned it on but in the real org its turned on from what I can see.

Here is what I can see. As I have field history tracking turned on for both 1 and 2 I can see history object for both in their respective page layouts under the related tabs.

What I want to see is Custom object 1 's history on custom object 2 under the related list but I can't get it to show up. I can see that people have been successful in my org in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that currently there is no feature and this was a custom built solution. To do the same use your own custom solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34384331)